# How to execute the download and processing in parallel for the Spring SFTP integration processing?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, sftp

Cannot multithread on an inbound SFTP Spring integration.
Want the service activator to activate on a separate thread as soon as the poller picks a file . With the below code, the serviceactivator comes into picture only after all the files are processed by the messageSource.  If the input sftp director has more than 2gb files its taking so long to reach the service activator. Did I miss anything ?

```
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        factory.setHost(sftpHost);
        factory.setPort(sftpPort);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        factory.setUser(sftpUser);
        factory.setPassword(sftpPassword);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean(name="defaultsync")
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer(){
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sync = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(createNewSFTPSessionFactory());
        sync.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        sync.setRemoteDirectory(sftpDirectory);
        sync.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
        return sync;
    }

    @Bean(name="sftpMessageSource")
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel="fileuploaded", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "3000"))
    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource(){
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
                new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(synchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\myfolder"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setMaxFetchSize(-1);
        return source;
    }


    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileuploaded")
    public void handleIncomingFile(File file) throws IOException {
        log.info(String.format("handleIncomingFile BEGIN %s", file.getName()));
        String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
        log.info(String.format("Content: %s", content));
        if(awsFileService.putFileInAWSS3(file))
        System.out.println("Processed file : "+file.getName());

    }
```

How can I call the ServiceActivator as soon as the file is received by the messageSource ? Any pointers would be appreciated.

**Update**

There were 3 problems : 1.) Because the fetch size was set to negative number, it will call the serviceactivator only after all of the files in input channel are processed.

2.) Absence of filter causing same file to repeatedly get processed .Had to add filter.

3.) Because of the datasize and the number of files to be processed , the SimpleMetadatastore approach was failing , so had to use jdbc store in the filter.

Got the below error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO INT_METADATA_STORE(METADATA_KEY, METADATA_VALUE, REGION) SELECT ?, ?, ? FROM INT_METADATA_STORE WHERE METADATA_KEY=? AND REGION=? HAVING COUNT(*)=0]; SQL state [S0002]; error code [208]; Invalid object name 'INT_METADATA_STORE'
```

**Problem resolved by adding the below code and by adding the default spring datasource**

```
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

   @Bean(name="defaultsync")
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer(){
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sync = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(createNewSFTPSessionFactory());
        sync.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        sync.setRemoteDirectory(sftpDirectory);
       // sync.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
        sync.setFilter(getFilter());
        return sync;
    }

    public ChainFileListFilter<DirEntry> getFilter()
    {
        ChainFileListFilter<DirEntry> chainFilter = new ChainFileListFilter<>();
        chainFilter.addFilter(new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(".*\\.(xml|XML)"));
        chainFilter.addFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(getMetadataStore(),"MyPrefix"));
        return chainFilter;
    }
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMetadataStore getMetadataStore()
    {
        return new JdbcMetadataStore(dataSource);
    }
```

Also had to run the script for my database from the following link :

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/main/spring-integration-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/jdbc

Now the files are getting processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
source.setMaxFetchSize(-1);
```

This means fetch all files that pass the filter first; `source.setMaxFetchSize(1);` will fetch files one-at-a-time.

Comment: I changed it to a positive number 2. It picks only 2 files and then stops.  But I see the following message in the log even though it copies- both the files successfully into local.   "The remote file 'Xml_test77782.xml[null]: type=1;size=23858;uid=0;gid=0;perms=0x8140;flags=[Size, Perms, AccessTime, ModifyTime, CreateTime];owner=null;group=null;aTime=2023-03-16T13:17:10Z;cTime=2022-09-08T04:32:12Z;mTime=2022-09-07T08:50:07Z;extensions=[]' has not been transferred to the existing local file 'C:\temp\Xml_test77782.xml'. Consider removing the local file"

Comment: You need to use a `CompositeFileListFilter` or `ChainFileListFilter` with an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` or , preferably an `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` together with your pattern filter to prevent fetching a file again.

Comment: Don't put code and stack traces in comments; it's too hard to read; edit the question instead so you can format it using markdown; just comment that you have done so. It looks like you have not created the tables. Better to delete these comments and do it now. It looks like you haven't created the table; the schema SQL is in the jar or here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/main/spring-integration-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/jdbc You can also test it with a `SimpleMetadataStore` (in memory) or a `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore`.

Comment: Thank you @Gary Russell. Modified the question and added updates. Now the problem is slowness. Have to multithread. Upvoted your answer.

Comment: Declare `fileUploaded` as an `ExecutorChannel` so the poller hands off the processing to another thread and continues to fetch file(s).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75773560/is-this-executorchannel-getting-all-the-tasks-from-the-message-channel , tried executor channel . But its not performing upto mark.

Comment: Suggest you ask a new question showing the current state of your code.

Comment: Hi Gary, Did that . It was in the comment above. Attaching it again.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75773560/is-this-executorchannel-getting-all-the-tasks-from-the-message-channel